# When is this complex-valued function analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

$$f(z) = e^{z}(z-\overline{z})^2\\=-4e^z(\Im(z))^2$$

I'm not sure if I could just determine where it's analytic here by considering this expression, so I let $z = x+iy$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

$$f(z) = -4e^{x}e^{iy}y^2$$
so the jacobian matrix with the partial derivatives are

$$J = \begin{pmatrix}-4y^2 e^{x}\cos y & -4e^{x}(2y \cos y - y^2 \sin y) \\ -4y^2 e^x \sin y & -4e^x (2y\sin y + y^2 \cos y)\end{pmatrix}$$

and the Cauchy Riemann equations only satisfy if
$y = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
This means that $f$ is analytic for only complex numbers with imaginary component multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

However, I doubt this answer because if I let (for example) $z = x + 1i$, then
$$f(z) = -4e^x e^{i}$$
which seems to be differentiable (since $e^x$ is differentiable) and the rest are just constants. So it seems to me that any possible complex number can allow $f$ to be analytic (since any $y$ value would give a differentiable function $e^x$ in the end result (but obviously not satisfying the CR equations)) 
Do I have some sort of misconception about differentiability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, for $f$ be $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable at $x+iy$ the following conditions must be satisfied:
$$-4y^2e^x \cos y = -4e^x(2y \sin y+y^2\cos y),$$
$$ 4e^x(2y \cos y-y^2\sin y)=-4y^2 e^x \sin y,$$
which can be simplified to
$$ y\sin y = 0,$$
$$ y \cos y = 0.$$
So only points with $y=0$ satisfy the CR equations, so $f$ can be $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable only at points on the line $y=0.$

When you evaluate $f$ at $x+i$ you get the result $f(z)=-4e^xe^i,$ but you can't know if $f$ is $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable at some point by evaluating $f$ at the point, that's just the value that $f$ takes at that point.

Now note that $f$ can't be analytic at any point, since if $f$ is analitic at some point, then it is $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable in some neighborhood of the point. But $f$ can be $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable only at points on the line $y=0,$ so any neighborhood of a point at which $f$ is $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable must contain points at which $f$ is not.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't take the "and" results of both conditions.  
Hmm, but then won't we just have the function $f(x) = -4e^x e^i$ (since we aren't fixing $x$)?

Comment: $f$ is the function defined on all $\mathbf{C}$ by $f(x,y)=-4e^xe^{iy}y^2.$ If you fix $y=1,$ then $f(x,1)=-4e^{x}e^i$ for all values of $x,$ but that's the value of $f$ only in the vertical line $y=1.$ You can't use the function $-4x^xe^i$ instead of $f$ since differentiability implies taking a limit from all approaches, not only from one line $y=1.$